# Convert java.sql.connection to groovy

Tags: groovy

I've got a library that I'm using to get database connections. It's returning a java.sql.Connection object. Now I could just write java to run my query, but I'm coding in Groovy and I'd love to use Groovy's SQL classes. Is there any way to go from one to the other?

Answer (score 0):

Just instantiate it with the Connection object. I feel silly for having asked something so simple.

```
Sql sql = new Sql(connection)
```

Comment: you could delete your question

Comment: I'm hesistant. StackOverflow doesn't like when you delete answered questions